# Undefined variable: users (View: /home/swit/public_html/manager/resources/views/users.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i keep getting this error and i don't know what's wrong.
The code seems correct so please help me if you can figure out what's giving me this error. "Undefined variable: users (View: /home/swit/public_html/manager/resources/views/users.blade.php)
"
thanks

this is my blade.php

```
        <tbody>
                                                                                                                                    
             @foreach ($users as $key)
             <tr>
                <td>{{$key->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$key->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$key->phone}}</td>
                <td>{{$key->created_at}}</td>        
            </tr>
            @endforeach
      </tbody>
```

and this is my controller

```
             <?php

                namespace App\Http\Controllers;
                use Illuminate\Http\Request;
                use App\Models\Admin;
                use App\Models\User;
                use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

                class UserController extends Controller
                  {
                     public function user(){
                     $users = DB::table('users')->get();
                     return view('users', compact('users'));
                     }
                  }
```

and this is my route

```
                     Route::get('/users', function () {
                      return view('users');
                      })->middleware(['auth'])->name('users');
```

Answer (score 1):

change your route function definition for the controller

```
Route::get('/users', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'user'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your route file, You should create a route which use controller and not an function as you have define,

When you define a route using closure, that function will be executed on each request that match that route.

You should define a route to that controller like this

```
// At the top of the web.php file    
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

// Here you define the route
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'user']])
    ->middleware(['auth'])->name('users');
```